# how to identify a field separator from scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to read a text file which has names with numbers like below.

```
rENLAg:12182
TgAlKd:19773
SSqUpz:16466
QYStPh:4113
CodNhz:28920
SgoIGz:25343
```

I need to separate the letters from the numbers.fscanf only identifies spaces, but not other field separators. Therefore how do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution would be to use scan sets (see the entry for *Conversion specifier* **[set]** in the [format specifiers table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)):

```
char buf[7];
int i;
/* Check result of fscanf(), which returns the number
   of assignments made, to ensure both 'buf' and 'i'
   were assigned values. */
if (fscanf(fp, " %6[^:]:%d", buf, &i) == 2)
{
}
```

where `" %6[^:]"` means skip any leading whitespace (new-line character from previous read for example) and read up to, but not including, the first `:` character but no more than 6 characters (to prevent buffer overrun).

Comment: This is a really nice example of proper scanf usage.

Comment: if both the string part and the number is also need to be stored as string?

Comment: @DesirePRG, just `%5s` (or whatever max length of second part is - 1) and use a `char[]` as second argument.

Comment: The loops seems to be running only once.Only the first line is getting printed. What seems to be wrong? Should I post my code? I am using the above in a while loop.

Comment: I am trying to add these to a linked list, and this is my code.Only the first line is being read. http://ideone.com/9D6FoH#ul_inouterr

Comment: @DesirePRG, you need to copy `test` and `test2` otherwise all entries in your linked list will point to the same buffer.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that please? even if i put printf("%s %s",headptr->lastname,headptr->employeeID) it is the same result

Comment: use `strdup()` if available, otherwise `malloc()` and `strcpy()`. This is pointer assignment: `headptr->lastname=test;` it does *not copy* the content of `test`

Comment: Even with strdup the loop runs only once :(

Comment: @DesirePRG, you missing leading space in format specifier. It must be `" %6[^:]:%d"`.